# Symfony asset not including stylesheets

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4

I have symfony 4.1 installed via composer and the `asset` component.

I have a css file at `assets/css/dashboard.css` and in my `templates/base.html.twig` I included this:

```
    {% block stylesheets %}
        <link href="{{ asset('css/dashboard.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    {% endblock %}
```

I haven't modified anything, but somehow the template is not getting called.

I tried many variations of the path, adding slashes, dots thinking maybe the path is wrong but nothing.

The css file has no issue, I dumped it's contents and pasted it inside my template's `<style></style>` tags and it works.

I don't know what is going on

Comment: If you are talking about the `assets` folder that is in the root of your project - and not in `public` - you need to use for example webpack to build / copy the file to the correct location.

Comment: Try `bin/console assets:install`

Comment: @jeroen That makes sense. Is there a way to build it using webpack? I could search online guides, but I'm sure there will be many initial errors or configuration problems. If you can answer with the steps, I can accept that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For short:**

The `asset()` function points on your public folder.

So in your example, your `dashboard.css` should be in `public/css/dashboard.css` than this `<link href="{{ asset('css/dashboard.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />` should work.

**The longer explanation:**

Usually you will structure your scripts, styles and images in your `assets` folder. But in production you don´t need good readable css/less/scss/js code and so you want to minify it.
And the minified (uglified) code should be copied to your `public` folder.

So you want to use `Webpack Encore` to minify your code and "deploy" it to your projects `public` folder.

In symfony´s [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html#gsc.tab=0) you can find a [simple Example](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html) how to use [Webpack Encore](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html).

**Why the assets are going to the public folder?**

During the security concept of symfony (and the most other frameworks) the `public` folder is the only accessible folder. So everything the browser have to read goes there. In case of symfony your styles, scripts, images and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. is there any alternative with example you can give that does not require me to change from assets to public folder to use css or js files? I feel the assets folder is there for a reason and I don't want to change it

Comment: Usually you build and minify your assets and copy them to your public folder with webpack. 
I think [the official simple example](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html) will help you. And [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html) you find the installation guide.

Comment: perfect answer.

Comment: one last question, i have worked with less and sass before, and i just realized I can create sass file in assets and have the build placed in public. what advantages does encore have over this?

Comment: It is made by symfony and so it has a good integration into symfony projects. Of course you can use other things like gulp, grunt etc. 
In my opinion encore is the right way in symfony projects, because it is build in.